# Get rid of whitespace between divs

Tags: html, css

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/u2p7fbkm/

HTML:

```
<div id="alt-color">
    <p> First</p>
</div>

<div id="main-color">
    <h2>Second</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#alt-color {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
#main-color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

How can I remove the whitespace between the divs (first and Second) in the example? Basically I want something like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h2` and `p` and other tags like `h1` have , by default, margins ( top and/or bottom ) . Just remove the margins using css.

As an advice, always use the dev tools provided by every browser ( right click -> inspect element ) and check the styles applied to your elements. Will save you a lot of time in the future.

```css
#alt-color{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);

}
#main-color{
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

p, h2 {
 margin:0
}
```

```html
  <div id="alt-color">
    <p> First</p>
  </div>

  <div id="main-color">
    <h2>Second</h2>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`h2` and `p` tags have margins. Remove them with `margin: 0`:

```css
#alt-color {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
#main-color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
p, h2{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="alt-color">
    <p> First</p>
</div>

<div id="main-color">
    <h2>Second</h2>
</div>
```

Alternatively:

```css
#alt-color {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
#main-color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
div{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="alt-color">
    <p> First</p>
</div>

<div id="main-color">
    <h2>Second</h2>
</div>
```